# A "RuntimeError" is throw when I start my app on flask. Below is the code I have that makes it to fail

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

So to give context, a mail is supposed to be sent after 5secs when the app has been started. But when I start the app, an error is thrown. Below is the error:

```
(learning_map_api) Eloka-Chima:learning_map_api andeladeveloper$ 
gunicorn main:app --worker-class gevent
[2018-03-03 10:02:48 +0100] [60007] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
[2018-03-03 10:02:48 +0100] [60007] [INFO] Listening at: 
http://127.0.0.1:8000 (60007)
[2018-03-03 10:02:48 +0100] [60007] [INFO] Using worker: gevent
[2018-03-03 10:02:48 +0100] [60010] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 
60010
Job "<lambda> (trigger: interval[0:00:05], next run at: 2018-03-03 
10:02:50 WAT)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 988, in __call__
return self.registry[key]
KeyError: <Greenlet at 0x10f1c6638: <bound method Thread._bootstrap of 
<Thread(ThreadPoolExecutor-1_0, started daemon 4548486712)>>>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/apscheduler/executors/base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/Desktop/learning_map_api/main.py", line 228, in <lambda>
scheduler.add_job(lambda: FlaskMailService().send_mail(email),
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/Desktop/learning_map_api/api/core/services/email_service/flask_mail_service.py", line 39, in send_mail
self.content = self.__notification_template()
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/Desktop/learning_map_api/api/core/services/email_service/flask_mail_service.py", line 55, in __notification_template
_contributions = Contribution.query.order_by(
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 498, in __get__
return type.query_class(mapper, session=self.sa.session())
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 78, in __call__
return self.registry()
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/_collections.py", line 990, in __call__
return self.registry.setdefault(key, self.createfunc())
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2867, in __call__
return self.class_(**local_kw)
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
self.app = app = db.get_app()
File "/Users/andeladeveloper/.virtualenvs/learning_map_api/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 957, in get_app
'application not registered on db instance and no application'
RuntimeError: application not registered on db instance and no applicationbound to current context
```

Below is where I created a method that handles the creation of an instance of `Flask` app:

```
def create_flask_app(environment):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_folder=None)
    app.config.from_object(app_configuration[environment])

    CORS(app)

    # initialize SQLAlchemy
    models.db.init_app(app)

    # initilize migration commands
    Migrate(app, models.db)

    # initilize api resources
    api = Api(app)
```

Below is what I have done using `with app.app_context()` to provide context to which app it will use:

```
def create_flask_app(environment):
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True, static_folder=None)
    app.config.from_object(app_configuration[environment])
    with app.app_context():
        CORS(app)

        # initialize SQLAlchemy
        models.db.init_app(app)

        # initilize migration commands
        Migrate(app, models.db)

        # initilize api resources
        api = Api(app)
```

Below is where the method is being called:

```
app = create_flask_app(os.getenv("FLASK_CONFIG") or "development")
ADMIN_SENDER = os.environ.get('ADMIN_SENDER')
recipients = [
    'my-app@gmail.com',
]
email = {
    'config': app,
    'subj': "Notification",
    'from': ADMIN_SENDER,
    'to': recipients,
    'contrib_title': None
}
scheduler.add_job(lambda: FlaskMailService().send_mail(email),
              'interval', seconds=5, id='send_mail',
              start_date='2017-11-16 23:30:00',
              timezone="Africa/Lagos")
atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown(wait=False))
scheduler.start()
```

Having tried using `with app.app_context()`, it still throws the error above.
What am I not doing correctly?

Comment: It would be great if you could put the code and error message in the question not in an image.

Comment: @NonStatic done. Can you review and give your comment? Thanks

Comment: What is `FlaskMailService()`?

Comment: `FlaskMailService()` is a class. I just imported it there to use its method `send_mail()` .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `FlaskMailService` class accesses the database, so it needs to have a Flask application context installed for that to work. Without an application context, Flask-SQLAlchemy does not have a way to access the configuration, which tells it where is your database located.

The solve this, pass the `app` instance to the background job, and then create an application context before your run your service task:

```
with app.app_context():
    # do your db/mail things here
```

Comment: I have updated the question to provide more context, and to express what I have done before seeking help. Can you go true it again and maybe suggest the appropriate place where I will use `with app.app_context()`

Comment: You are not showing enough of your code for me to show you that. As I said in my answer, pass the `app` instance into your scheduled job as an argument, then wrap any code that needs to access the database in the app context.